# How Do You Specify A Runtime Dependency On IBM WAS?

Tags: gradle, websphere, websphere-8

I have a web application deployed on IBM WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.

It uses JNDI to look up a `com.ibm.websphere.cache.DistributedMap` which comes from the websphere classpath at runtime.

However, I need access to that class in order to compile the code and not all developers or build servers have an instance of WebSphere installed.

The gradle war plugin has a `providedCompile` configuration to hold this dependency but where do I get the jar containing the `DistributedMap`?

Does IBM have a public repo with the WebSphere runtime jars in it?

Or do I need to extract it from an installed instance and publish it to our internal company maven repo?

Which jar contains this class?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this will solve your issue, this looks like maven repo with DistributedMap API https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.distributedMap